# Retry function promise if we get a certain result

Tags: javascript, json

I'm so close to having this working. This code queries an API to return a reportID, then queries it again with the reportID to get the data.

```
function myfunction(ref) {
  getReport(ref, "queue", "hour", "2018-10-03", "2018-10-04", "pageviews", "page").done(function(r1) {
    getReport(r1.reportID, "get").done(function(r2) {
      if (r2.error == "report_not_ready") {
        console.log("Not ready");
        setTimeout(function() {
          myfunction(ref)
        }, 1000);
      }
      console.log(r2);
    })
  });
}


function getReport(ref, type, granularity, from, to, metric, element) {
  return $.getJSON("report.php", {
    ref: ref,
    type: type,
    granularity: granularity,
    from: from,
    to: to,
    metric: metric,
    element: element,
  });
}
```

The issue with this code is, sometimes the report isn't ready when we try and get it, so we need to retry in a bit. The code as I have it at the moment re-runs the entire report again if it returns not ready, including generating a new report ID.

What it is meant to do is just retry the original reportID.

Can anyone help me understand how to do this please?

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on the behavior of your server side script? Also, if the report isn't ready when you call for it, why not just have your XHR wait until it is done? That's really the point of having asynchronous requests anyway, so that **they** can wait on the server to respond, and your users don't have to. Unless I have misunderstood your question, which may well be so.

Comment: @KamilJarosz There may well be a better way to do this, but I was told to use promises so that I could put the data from the call into a different function when it is ready. Keen to know if you have a better way.

Comment: How long does the report typically take to generate? Are you able to modify it at all? If it's not like a really long running processed, I'd change the server side to not return an error unless the server actually failed to generate the report. The nature of the asynchronous request will just let your code continue normally. Your UI will continue to function and then once the server responds, you can just insert the value of the report into your view. One ajax call, no need for retries. Out of curiosity, can you show us what `report.php` is doing? We might be able to make better suggestions.

Comment: According to the js if the report is being generated by the server but not ready yet the error code "report_not_ready" is expected and it is the only case where the retry is needed so I am not sure what else we would need to know. Then again, assuming that the "report_not_ready" code is not returned by default for any error.

Comment: This is not to say it cannot be done this way. I'm only saying there might be a more sensible approach where a retry is not needed in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code calls the api 3 times and then exits,

```
function reportHandler(id, r2, retries){
    if(retries >= 3){
        console.log("tried 3 times")
        return
    }
    if (r2.error == "report_not_ready") {
        console.log("Not ready");
        setTimeout(function() {
          getReport(id, "get").done(r2=>reportHandler(id, r2, retries + 1))
        }, 1000);
      }
      console.log(r2);
}

function myfunction(ref) {
  getReport(ref, "queue", "hour", "2018-10-03", "2018-10-04", "pageviews", "page").done(function(r1) {
    getReport(r1.reportID, "get").done(r2=>reportHandler(r1.reportID, r2, 0))
  });
}
```

Comment: This code works perfectly, only issue is it doesn't exit out of the code after three failed retries, but it does correctly say "tried 3 times"

Comment: @Jimmy yeah, it should return inside the if block, updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

From the code it seems you only need to re-fetch the result for `r2`, in that case I suggest you extract it to its own method like this:

```
function myfunction(ref) {
    getReport(ref, "queue", "hour", "2018-10-03", "2018-10-04", "pageviews", "page").done(function (r1) {
        getReportFromId(r1.reportID);
    });
}

function getReportFromId(reportId) {
    getReport(reportId, "get").done(function (r2) {
        if (r2.error == "report_not_ready") {
            console.log("Not ready");
            setTimeout(function () {
                getReportFromId(reportId)
            }, 1000);
        }
        console.log(r2);
    })
}

function getReport(ref, type, granularity, from, to, metric, element) {
    return $.getJSON("report.php", {
      ref: ref,
      type: type,
      granularity: granularity,
      from: from,
      to: to,
      metric: metric,
      element: element,
    });
}
```

That way your retry only covers the second retrieval.